# send multiple params to hash

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

hy 
I parse file for find some params like uid,dbname and url.
what i try to do is  to get all value in hash for sending it in csv file

when i parse my hash (res_licence)  i only have 3 params like that

uid, uid'] = 'adfs';
url, url'] = 'https://mydom.sandboxbk.net';
dbname,

i cant find why he override :(

```
res_licence = Hash.new

array = Dir.glob('configuration_*')
array.each do |f|
       file = File.open(f ,"r")
      lines = file.readlines

  lines.each do |line|

  if line.include? 'uid'
     uid = line.match(/(?=uid)(.*)/)
     puts ""
     puts "==>#{uid} "
     #res_licence = { uid: uid}
  end 


 if line.include? 'url'
     url = line.match(/(?=url)(.*)/)
     puts "==>#{url} "
       #res_licence = {  url: url}
  end 


 if line.include? 'dbname'
     dbname = line.match(/(?=dbname)(.*)/)
     puts "=>#{dbname} "

  end 
    res_licence = {uid: uid, url: url, dbname: dbname}
   end

 end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a solution to my problem, and this times i dont have uid => "xxx", url=> "xxx"

```
configs = {}
Dir.glob('configuration_*').each do |filename|
 configs[filename]= Hash.new
  File.foreach(filename) do |line|


         if line.include? 'uid'
              next unless line.match(/(?=uid).*?[\'\"].*?[\'\"](.*?)[\'\"](.*?)[\;\"]/)
                field, value = line.split("=",2);
             ( configs[filename] = []  <<  value.strip.gsub("';", "").gsub("'",""))
               #( configs[filename][:uid] ||= [] ) <<  value.strip.gsub("';", "").gsub("'","") 
         end
   CSV.open("/tmp/data.csv", "wb", Options = {quote_char: "\0" }) {|csv| configs.each {|input| csv << input }}
```

now i have a last problem when i execute the script i get that in output

```
configuration_groupe-poult.mydomain.net.php,["group", "https://groupe-poult.mydomain.net", "group"]
configuration_kb-in.mydomain.net.php,["kbin", "https://kb-in.mydomain.net", "kauf"]
```

how i can remove the hook'[ ] and the quote " ?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the variables are local inside the blocks where you assign them. Add this at the beginning of your script:

```
uid = nil
url = nil
dbname = nil
```